# javascript function always returns false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to validate a html form using jquery,ajax and php. I've written  this function in jquery that checks for the availability of a username using ajax post request.However, the problem is that it is always returning a false. I'm new to jquery and javascript. I've tried quite a bit but I'm unable to figure out the problem. Please help.

```
function isvalid_username()
{
var username=$('#username').val();
var option=false;
        if(username == "")
        {
            $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Please choose a username!!");
            option=false;
        }
        else if(username.length < 4)
        {
            $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Your username must be atleast 4 characters.");
            option=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $.post('php/check_username_avail.php',{ username : username },function(data){

                if(data == "false")
                {

                    $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Sorry! That username is already taken. Try a different one.");
                    option= false;
                }
                else if(data == "true")
                {
                    $('#username').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                    $('#username_feedback').html("");
                    alert('Now it should return true');
                     option=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html(data);
                    option=false;
                }
            }).error(function(){
                alert("An error occurred. Unable to validate username");
            });
        }
        return option;
}
```

**EDIT**: I've read the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). But I still don't find a way to validate the form. I want to use this submit handler function with my code:

```
$('#signup_form').submit(function(event)
{
  if(isvalid_first_name() && isvalid_username() && isvalid_email() && isvalid_password())
  {
    alert('Submitting the form');
  }
  else
  {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#submit_feedback').html("Please correct the above problems first");
  }

});
```

If it can't be done this way, then what other technique should I use to validate the form on clientside?

Comment: FYI, `error` is deprecated, use `fail`

Comment: Ok! done. Also understood the problem with my code. But didn't get the solution.

Comment: If I use promises, Then how should I change my handler so that the form validation is not affected?

Answer (score 0):

Well because you not waiting for AJAX to complete and returning option right away which is already false. Try below code.

```
    function isvalid_username(){
      var username=$('#username').val();
      var option=false;
        if(username == "")
        {
            $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Please choose a username!!");
             return option;
        }
        else if(username.length < 4)
        {
            $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Your username must be atleast 4 characters.");
             return option;
        }
        else
        {
            $.post('php/check_username_avail.php',{ username : username },function(data){

                if(data == "false")
                {

                    $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html("Sorry! That username is already taken. Try a different one.");
                     return option;
                }
                else if(data == "true")
                {
                    $('#username').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                    $('#username_feedback').html("");
                    alert('Now it should return true');
                    option=true;
                    return option;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#username').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                    $('#username_feedback').addClass('error').html(data);
                     return option;
                }
            }).error(function(){
                alert("An error occurred. Unable to validate username");
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return from ajax call. In jquery, this will always returns the promise interface